# How to return view with dynamic field in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes

I have an html page called `profile.blade.php`, which contains an anchor tag:

```
<a href="{{ route('profile', $user->id) }}">{{$user->name}}</a>
```

I have a route like this:

```
Route::get('/profile/{id}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profile');
```

I have a `ProfilesController` in which the index method returns an the user who owns the profile:

```
public function index()
{
   $userId = //somehow get the data sent from the anchor tag

   $user = $this->usersService->getProfileOwner($userId);

   return view("profile", [
      'user' => $user ?? []
   ]);
}
```

How can I change this code, so for example when user with id 1 visits the profile of user with id 2, the index function returns the details of user 2 to the `blade` template ?

Comment: have you tried `request()->id`?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel auto bind class to method

```
use App\User;

public function index(User $user)
{
   return view("profile",compact('user'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

AS the answers above, I'd suggest you to use the model binding.

But in your code, you can do:

```
public function index($id)
{
    $user = $this->usersService->getProfileOwner($id);

    return view("profile", [
       'user' => $user ?? []
    ]);
}
```

If $id is always int, you can also type-hint it.